# Finding SUM except some columns

Tags: excel, sum, formula, excel-formula

Below is what I have.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  A  +  B  +  C  +  D  +  E  +  F  +  G  +  H  +  I  +  J  +  K  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  +  2  +  3  +  4  +  5  +  6  +  7  +  8  +  9  +  10 +  50 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

To find the **SUM** of this row excluding `Cell E` I am using formulae as below.

**`=SUM(A1:D1)+SUM(F1:J1)`**

***NOTE : `Cell K` have SUM.***

Is there any alternate way??

Above is just an example however in my sheet there are around 100 columns and I need to exclude around 10-15 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a row like this:

```
Row2: yes yes yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes no ...
```

(being columns A:K)

Then the answer could be

```
=SUMIF(2:2,"yes",1:1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe

```
=SUM(A1:J1)-E1
```

conveys your intention more clearly. (provided the excluded columns contain numbers, of course)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am looking for more answer. Maybe some other way. I think this would be more better then HaunsTM answer as I need to write less.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that this is an alternate way

```
=SUM(A1:D1;F1:J1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am looking for more answer. Maybe some other way...

Answer (score 1):

The common approach to address this problem in Excel is to apply the `SUM` function to the entire range and to substract the exception list out of it, again with the `SUM` function, this time with a discrete list of individual cells to sum:

```
=SUM(<range to sum>)-SUM(<exception cell 1>, <exception cell 2>, ...)
```

This applied to your current example of ~100 cells to sum with say 5 exceptions:

```
=SUM(A1:CV1)-SUM(E1,M1,Y1,AB1,BU1)
```

If you want to get your Excel spreadsheet more flexible to those columns exclusion, you may consider to define a named range on the discrete selection of your columns to exclude. If you use it in the substraction `SUM` formula, you will avoid to change the formula when additional columns need to be excluded : you will only need to change the named range specification.

```
=SUM(A1:J1)-SUM(A1:J1 Exclusion_List)
```

where `Exclusion_List` is a named range on the distinct columns to exclude

Comment: You might want to mention the subtle (but significant!) meaning of the space in `SUM(A1:J1 Exclusion_List)` (^: