# Is it possible to use sum range in excel with exception of some column in the middle?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum from column A1 to column E1 excluding column C1.

[image]

How can i do this using SUM range formula

> =SUM(A1:E1) exclude C1

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775651/6075259) helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbers in C so you can do it like that:

```
=SUM(A1:E1)-C1
```

It is not a nice formula but doing what you want

Comment: I up voted your answer because it makes sense but what if i have more than one column to exclude lets just say =SUM(A1:A100) i want to exclude 20 column. How can i do this?

Comment: Than you do =`SUM(A1:E1)-SUM(W1:AW1)`

Comment: and - if it helped you - please check it as the good answer

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(A1:B1)+SUM(D1:E1)
```

This works better as it doesn't assume numbers in Column C

Comment: Thank you for this, i already have an idea what to do.